# Select a dummy column with a dummy value in Zend framework Select?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db

How can i specify `Zend Db Table Select` to fetch a dummy column.

i want to generate sql like this

`SELECT 'ABC' AS xyz , name  FROM employee`

**Edit:**

I have tried this

```
$select->from('employee',array( 
        'xyz'=>'ABC',
        'name'
));
```

and also as

`$select->from('employee',"'ABC' AS xyz , name"));`

in both cases Zend intelligently considers 'ABC' as a field in schema. so it generate something like

```
SELECT `employee`.`'ABC'` AS `xyz` , `name` FROM `employee`
```

which produces error as ABC is not a field of employee

Comment: Can't you just add those columns in your code? Why do you need those "dummy columns"?

Comment: i have edited my question. please re read, i appreciate you quick response

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should try

```
$select->from ('employee', array (new Zend_Db_Expr ('"ABC" AS title'), 'name'));
```

Comment: And how can make its alias like 'ABC' AS title ?

Comment: Add an AS statement: `new Zend_Db_Expr ('"ABC" AS title')`